# Django - Form used in editing data from extended user model doesn't show previous data as placeholder

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I use following code:

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)   
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.imie
```

views.py

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {
        
        'profile_form': ProfileForm
    })
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location')
```

edit.html

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Save changes</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Following code should allow the user to edit data stored in Profile model and it does exactly that, however form is loaded empty (without placeholder) and I would like it to display previous values.

Edit: where the link to edit.html is anchored
it's just a simple verions of a profile page where just plain data is displayed

```
{% for things in logged_in_user_data %}
<ul>
<li>Your location: <a href="{% url 'edit' %}">{{ things.location}}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

with it's views.py

```
def profile(request):
    logged_in_user_data = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'logged_in_user_data': logged_in_user_data})
```

Comment: After the line `profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)` write `print(profile.location)` what output does that give you? Also you don't appear to show the complete `Profile` model, do you have any custom `save` method or so on that? Please show the complete model. Also if you have anything more in the form class not present in the question show that too.

Comment: It appears to give no output at all, and this is a complete model code, there is nothing more. Should there be a custom ```save``` method for it to work?

Comment: Although I am using a changed user model so that a user can use email as login without username

Comment: `print(profile.location)` prints nothing? Or is it `None` or an empty line? If it prints **nothing** then it means that either this view is not even being used or you wrote it in some condtional which was False. Please edit and show where you wrote it. If it is an empty line there is no value for `location` saved for the profile instance i.e. it is an empty string.

Comment: It was the dictionary it should've been {'profile_form': profile_form}

Answer (score 1):

In the case the request is not a POST request you have still written `ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)`. What does this signify? It means that this form is now a **bound form** and a user has submitted some data to it (which here was empty since the request was not a post request). This causes the form to be rendered empty since it is considered that the user had provided those empty values. Instead you need to not pass `request.POST` here:

```python
def edit(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user) # Move common line here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile) # No `request.POST` here
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {
        # Typo noted as per comment by @A67John
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it didn't work, with the changes data is still editable but it is still rendered empty

Comment: @A67John how do you reach this page? Can you show the anchor tag or button or whatever the user clicks to reach this page? Plus I had truncated some of your code in the answer previously, which I have now added for clarity, please check that.

Comment: I have edited my question to show you how it can be reached. Also I double checked and I changed the code just as you suggested and it is still rendered empty